# Confusing systemd behaviour with OnFailure= and Restart=

Tags: systemd, services

I'm using systemd 231 in an embedded system, and I'm trying to create a service that monitors a hardware component in the system. Here's a rough description of what I'm trying to do:

1. When the service, `foo.service`, is started, it launches an application, `foo_app`.
2. `foo_app`monitors the hardware component, running continuously.
3. If `foo_app` detects a hardware failure, it exits with a return code of 1. This should trigger a system reboot.
4. If `foo_app` crashes, systemd should relaunch `foo_app`.
5. If `foo_app` *repeatedly* crashes, systemd should reboot the system.

Here's my attempt at implementing this as a service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Foo Hardware Monitor

# If the application fails 3 times in 30 seconds, something has gone wrong,
# and the state of the hardware can't be guaranteed. Reboot the system here.
StartLimitBurst=3
StartLimitIntervalSec=30
StartLimitAction=reboot

# StartLimitAction=reboot will reboot the box if the app fails repeatedly,
# but if the app exits voluntarily, the reboot should trigger immediately
OnFailure=systemd-reboot.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/foo_app

# If the app fails from an abnormal condition (e.g. crash), try to
# restart it (within the limits of StartLimit*).
Restart=on-abnormal
```

From the documentation ([systemd.service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) and [systemd.service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html)), I'd expect that if I kill `foo_app` in a way such that `Restart=on-abnormal` is  triggered (e.g. `killall -9 foo_app`), systemd should give priority to `Restart=on-abnormal` over `OnFailure=systemd-reboot.service` and not start `systemd-reboot.service`.

However, this isn't what I'm seeing. As soon as I kill `foo_app` once, the system immediately reboots.

Here are some relevant snippets from the docs:

> `OnFailure=`
>
> A space-separated list of one or more units that are activated when this unit enters the "failed" state. A service unit using Restart= enters the failed state only after the start limits are reached.
>
> `Restart=`
>
> *[snip]* Note that service restart is subject to unit start rate limiting configured with StartLimitIntervalSec= and StartLimitBurst=, see systemd.unit(5) for details. A restarted service enters the failed state only after the start limits are reached.

The documentation seems pretty clear:

- Services specified in `OnFailure` should only run when a service enters the "`failed`" state
- A service should only enter the "`failed`" state  after `StartLimitIntervalSec` and `StartLimitBurst` are satisfied.

This is not what I'm seeing.

To confirm this, I edited my service file to the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=Foo Hardware Monitor  
  
StartLimitBurst=3
StartLimitIntervalSec=30
StartLimitAction=none

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/foo_app
Restart=on-abnormal
```

By removing `OnFailure` and setting `StartLimitAction=none`, I was able to see how systemd is responding to `foo_app` dying. Here's a test where I repeatedly kill `foo_app` with `SIGKILL`.

```
[root@device ~]
# systemctl start foo.service
[root@device ~]
# journalctl -f -o cat -u foo.service &
[1] 2107
Started Foo Hardware Monitor.
[root@device ~]
# killall -9 foo_app
foo.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
foo.service: Unit entered failed state.
foo.service: Failed with result 'signal'
foo.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Stopped foo.
Started foo.

[root@device ~]
# killall -9 foo_app
foo.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
foo.service: Unit entered failed state.
foo.service: Failed with result 'signal'
foo.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Stopped foo.
Started foo.

[root@device ~]
# killall -9 foo_app
foo.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
foo.service: Unit entered failed state.
foo.service: Failed with result 'signal'
foo.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Stopped foo.
foo.service: Start request repeated too quickly
Failed to start foo.
foo.service: Unit entered failed state.
foo.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'
```

This makes sense or the most part. When `foo_app` is killed, systemd restarts it until `StartLimitBurst` is hit and then gives up. This is what I want, except with `StartLimitAction=reboot`.

What's unusual is that systemd prints `foo.service: Unit entered failed state.` whenever `foo_app` is killed, even if it is about to be restarted through `Restart=on-abnormal`. This seems to directly contradict these lines from the docs quoted above:

> A service unit using Restart= enters the failed state only after the start limits are reached.
>
> A restarted service enters the failed state only after the start limits are reached.

All of this has left me pretty confused. Am I misunderstanding any of these systemd options? Is this a systemd bug? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edit 2019/08/12:** Per `therealjumbo`'s comment, the fix for this has been merged and released with `systemd` v239, thus, if you aren't pinned to a version due to your distribution *(looking at you CentOS)* update and make merry!

TL;DR - Known documentation issue, currently still an outstanding issue for the `systemd` project

It turns out, since you asked this question, this has been reported and [identified as a discrepancy](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/8398) in `systemd` between the documentation and the actual behavior. In my understanding (and my reading of the github issue) your expectation and the documentation match, so you are not crazy.

Currently `systemd` sets the state to failed after every attempted start, regardless of whether the start limit has been reached. In the issue the OP wrote an amusing anecdote about learning to ride a bike that I highly suggest taking a gander at.

Comment: FYI, the upstream code was fixed to match the documentation. The fix was released in v239, PR is here: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/9158 Which is probably what most of us wanted.